# Subdomínio criado por usuário

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache, subdomínio

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de área de usuários, ao registrar-se, este usuário terá a sua área com seu subdomínio, escolhido por ele.

**Dúvida:**

Como fazer esse cadastro de subdomínio, sendo que ele não terá acesso ao cPanel.
Eu já vi isso em site gringo. Como posso fazer isto?
Pode ser pelo Apache, ou pelo próprio PHP.

Comment: Use a Api do Cpanel ou pesquise por WildCard - 

[Segue a API](https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar olhar o valor de `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`; essa variável contém a parte logo depois do `http://…`, até a primeira barra (vulgarmente, o “domínio” do site). Aí você só precisaria fazer um apontamento DNS e configurar o Apache pra fazer `qualquercoisa.meudominio.com` sempre cair no mesmo site (e portanto no seu script HTTP).